# What are the pros and cons of raising an error class vs. an instance of the class

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following appears to have the same effect:

```
>>> raise NotImplementedError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NotImplementedError

>>> raise NotImplementedError()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NotImplementedError
```

Is there a difference, and if so, what are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 5):

There is essentially no difference if the exception class requires no arguments for initialization:

> If an exception **class** is passed, it will be implicitly **instantiated** by
>   calling its constructor with no arguments.

[*Emphasis mine*]

Otherwise, you'll get another exception complaining about the initialization of the instance:

```
class MyException(Exception):
   def __init__(self, arg):
      pass

raise MyException
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Apparently, you can do more by passing custom arguments to custom exception classes, or passing a custom message to a builtin exception class:

```
>>> raise ValueError('number must be 42')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: number must be 42
```

The above is much more informative (quite desirable from a users' perspective) than a barren `ValueError`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference:

```
>>> try:
...     raise NotImplementedError
... except Exception as e:
...     pass
...
>>> e
NotImplementedError()
>>> type(e)
<type 'exceptions.NotImplementedError'>
>>> type(NotImplementedError)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(NotImplementedError())
<type 'exceptions.NotImplementedError'>
>>>
```

See section 8.4 of the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions